# Class override doesn't work anymore in Prestashop 1.7.6?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I simply need to add a custom field named 'color' in Category admin. I've always used this method in previous version but it seems that's not working anymore in 1.7.6 :

***override/classes/Category.php***

```php
    /**
     * Class CategoryCore
     */
    class Category extends CategoryCore
    {   
        public $color;    

        public function __construct($id_category = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null){

            self::$definition['fields']['color'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml');

            parent::__construct($id_category, $id_lang, $id_shop);

        }
    }
```

***override/controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php***

```php
class AdminCategoriesController extends AdminCategoriesControllerCore
    {
        public function renderForm()
        {
            $this->fields_form_override =array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->trans('Color', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'name' => 'color',
                    'maxlength' => 70,
                    'maxchar' => 70,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 5,
                    'cols' => 100,
                    'hint' => $this->trans('Forbidden characters:', array(), 'Admin.Notifications.Info').' <>;=#{}'
                ),
            );

            return parent::renderForm();
        }
    }
```

Finally, I added a text field in the Database (ps_category_lang) and I deleted all the cache.

The field doesn't appear. Someone has this problem? Do I need to use a module instead of this method?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this process is not longer supported in 1.7.6 version. We also need to **create a module with the new Symfony model**.

There is a french source that explain how to. [Here is the link](https://www.h-hennes.fr/blog/2019/08/05/prestashop-1-7-ajouter-des-champs-dans-un-formulaire-dadministration/).

I created a new post with my own code and the new procedure. I'm stucked in the save of the field in database. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552868/add-custom-field-in-prestashop-1-7-6-category-with-a-module-how-to-save-in-data).

Answer (score 1):

Same here, i don't know why its not working. I follow all the instruction.
Im using Prestashop 1.7.6, maybe this procedure is not working with the latest prestashop version. Because based on what i read, they use prestashop v1.6 older.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a module.
I tried your code and it work for me 
Try to clear cache in the backoffice interface and where are you put each file ?